# RSpec test uploaded xml file that fills out dynamic form

Tags: ruby, xml, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I am writing an automation test suite using RSpec, capybara, selenium web driver, and poltergeist. I do not have access to the codebase of the web app itself, only the test suite.

What happens is the client uploads an xml file, pieces of that xml file populate a form. The form is also dynamic, so fields can be added dependent on the contents of the xml file.

My mission is to write a test that ensures that the values of the xml file match what is being populated within the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is a sample of one of the xml files I am attempting to test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LOAN_APPLICATION>
<_DATA_INFORMATION>
<DATA_VERSION _Name="Date" _Number="20140926"/>
<DATA_VERSION _Name="1003" _Number="3.20"/>
</_DATA_INFORMATION>
<ADDITIONAL_CASE_DATA>
<TRANSMITTAL_DATA BelowMarketSubordinateFinancingIndicator="N" BuydownRatePercent="0.000" />
</ADDITIONAL_CASE_DATA>
<ASSET _CashOrMarketValueAmount="10000.00" />
<ASSET _AccountIdentifier="123456"/>
<ASSET _AccountIdentifier="1234567" _CashOrMarketValueAmount="100000.00" />
<ASSET _AccountIdentifier="6465456" _CashOrMarketValueAmount="50000.00" />
<InterviewersEmployerPostalCode="200121234" InterviewersTelephoneNumber="2023333333" ApplicationTakenMethodType="FaceToFace" InterviewerApplicationSignedDate="20111011" InterviewersEmployerName="ABC Mortgage" InterviewersName="John Done"/>

<CONTACT_POINT _Type="Email" _Value="Jimmy.Johns@abc.com"/>
</BORROWER>
</LOAN_APPLICATION>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John, you could create a fixture that reproduces an XML file like the one you pasted. Then you run your services, methods etc against it, and expect (or not) to parse back the contents of the fixture. You could also test another fixtures with invalid fields to ensure your app has contingencies to break down gracefully if there are any invalid fields.

Comment: Only problem is needs to be dynamic. So it needs to run any file upload against the form being filled out by the file upload.

Comment: Dynamic or not, once you upload you have a file. All you need is to test against all the possible cases/variations.